# Is it prescribed to seek refuge in Allah before listening to Quran?

Tags: quran, sunni

We know that we should seek refuge in Allah before reciting the Quran. Does the same ruling apply before we listen to the Quran?

I am asking regarding whether it is mandatory to seek refuge in Allah before listening to the Quran, I am not asking if it is okay to seek refuge in Allah before listening to the Quran or not.

Answer (score -1):

What is the reason and purpose of seeking refuge in God before reciting the Qur'an? The monotheistic man seeks help from God to gain benefit and goodness and begins his work with "In the name of God", and to repel harm and evil, he seeks help from him and begins his work with " I seek refuge in God".
Supplication means asking God for refuge. Before reciting the Qur'an, we seek refuge in God in order to make the most of the verses of the Qur'an and to avoid the temptations of Satan.
So what is wrong if we say this sentence to listen to the Qur'an and enjoy its light ?!

https://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/fa1579